# Can't change language using ```xskak``` package

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak, skak

I am studying chess and decided to take notes. So I am using `xskak` package. I decided to write in portuguese so that I can share with some friends. The package, however, doesn't obey my command. Here is a piece of working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
    \newskaklanguage{pt}{RDTBCP} %... renames pieces in sequence: KQRBNP
    \skaklanguage[pt]            %... selects language
    \usetextfig                  %... sets text algebra instead of icons
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{Abertura italiana}
Também conhecida como abertura \textit{Giuoco Piano}, que em italiano significa abertura tranquila.
Esta abertura, ilustrada na figura~\ref{Abertura italiana}, se caracteriza pela sequência de lances

\styleC
\newchessgame

\mainline{
    1. e4       e5
    }

\noindent
visando dominar o centro do tabuleiro, e

\mainline{
    2. Cf3      Cc6
    3. Bc4
    }

\noindent
visando desenvolver as peças menores.
O lance \variation{3. Bc4} visa atacar o peão mais fraco das pretas \emph{f7}, defendido apenas pelo rei.
As pretas podem responder com \variation{3... Bc5} ou com \variation{3... Cf6}.
A desvantagem do lance \variation{3... Cf6} é que ele bloqueia o avanço do peão \emph{f7}, motivando \variation{4. Cg5} que dá suporte ao bispo aumentando a pressão sobre o peão mais fraco do flanco do rei \emph{f7}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \xskakset{moveid=3w}
    \chessboard[
        setfen          = \xskakget{nextfen},
        showmover       = false,
        %-> SET ARROW:
        style           = warrowstyle,     %-> see def of warrowstyle @ _settings.tex
        markmoves       = {c4-f7},
        style           = barrowstyle,     %-> see def of warrowstyle @ _settings.tex
        markmoves       = {f8-c5},
        pgfstyle        = \rmove,
        markmoves       = {g8-f6},
        %--> SET DESTINY SQUARES:
        % style           = whighlightstyle, %-> see def of whighlightstyle @ _settings.tex
        % colorbackfields = {d5,e4},
        ]
    \caption{Abertura italiana.}
    \label{Abertura italiana}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that althou I wrote in Portuguese `2. Cf3 Cc6`, the output presents the algebra in English notation.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\skaklanguage`  sets the *input* language. To set the *output* language you must add another declaration (the commands are described in the *chessfss* documentation, that you can find on ctan).

I'm sorry that the syntax differ, but `\skaklanguage` is inherited from the skak package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
    \newskaklanguage{pt}{RDTBCP} %... renames pieces in sequence: KQRBNP
    \skaklanguage[pt]            %... selects language
    \usetextfig                  %... sets text algebra instead of icons
\settextfigchars[pt]{R}{D}{T}{B}{C}{P}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{ 1. e4 e5 2. Cf3 Cc6}

\settextfiglanguage{pt}
\newchessgame
\mainline{ 1. e4 e5 2. Cf3 Cc6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @UlrikeFischer. It works. And even better: you just showed that I don't need ```\newskaklanguage``` at all. I can keep writing the code in English notation and print it in Portuguese just with ```\settextfigcharts``` without the optional argument.